# Upload File Using NPM Request from new Formdata()

Tags: node.js, npm, request

i'am develop backend using `node-js` and https://www.npmjs.com/package/request to handdle request to main api.

has successfully to send data in the form of string or a number. but I have a problem to send the file. before getting to the request module, i have convert all request from client using

`new formdata()`

end this is what i code using NPM request

```
export function requestAPI(method='GET', endpoint='', params={}, callback)
{
    let token = ''
    if(params.token)
    {
        token = params.token;
        delete params.token;
    }

    //set query
    if(params.query)
    {
        endpoint = `${endpoint}?${Url.serialize(params.query)}`
        delete params.query
    }

    //set options
    let options = {
        method: method,
        uri: `${process.env.API_HOST}${endpoint}`,
        timeout: 6000,
        headers: {
            'auth' : token
        },
    };

    // upload files
    // ???

    // using POST method
    if(method === 'POST') {
        options['form'] = params;
    }

    // is upload a file - request via multipart/form-data


    //start request
    try {
        request( options , function(error, response, body){
            if(error)
            {
                console.log(error)
                return callback(httpException(500));
            } else //success
            {
                return callback(JSON.parse(body));
            }
        })
    } catch(err) {
        return callback(httpException(500, err.message+', '+err.stack));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for help guys, finaly i found the answer to solved it.

the problem on this line

```
if(method === 'POST') {
  options['form'] = params;
}
```

i just change to this, to make it works

```
if(method === 'POST') {
  options['formData'] = params;
}
```

and this is the complete of codes

```
export function requestAPI(method='GET', endpoint='', params={}, callback)
{
    let token = ''
    if(params.token)
    {
        token = params.token;
        delete params.token;
    }

    //set query
    if(params.query)
    {
        endpoint = `${endpoint}?${Url.serialize(params.query)}`
        delete params.query
    }

    //set options
    var options = {
        method: method,
        uri: `${process.env.API_HOST}${endpoint}`,
        timeout: 30000,
        headers: {
            'auth' : token
        },
    };

    // using POST method
    if(method.toLowerCase() === 'post') {
        options.formData = params;

        // upload files
        if(options.formData.files)
        {
            const files = options.formData.files
            delete options.formData['files']

            Object.keys(files).map(n => {
                options.formData[n] = {
                    value: fs.createReadStream(files[n]._writeStream.path),
                    options: {
                        filename: files[n].name,
                        type: files[n].type
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    //start request
    try {
        request( options , function(error, response, body){
            if(error)
            {
                return callback(httpException(500));
            } else //success
            {
                return callback(JSON.parse(body));
            }
        })
    } catch(err) {
        return callback(httpException(500, err.message+', '+err.stack));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For sending files you will need to use something like `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/json`. In addition, you will need to use the [`formData`](https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads) option instead of `form`. For example:

```
var options = {
    method: method,
    uri: `${process.env.API_HOST}${endpoint}`,
    timeout: 6000,
    headers: {
        'auth' : token,
    },
};

// using POST method
if (method === 'POST') {
    options.formData = params;
}
```

Then inside `params` you can use any values as outlined in the `request` and/or `form-data` modules' documentation. So for local files, you can just use a readable stream:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// ...

params.avatar = fs.createReadStream('avatar.jpg');
```

For files you can explicitly set a different filename and/or mime type as shown in the relevant [`request` multipart/form-data example](https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads).